# With vite, accessing an image which are missing, does not result in 404 error, but show index.html

Tags: vite

If i try to load following with axios:

http://localhost:5173/path/my_missing_image.jpg

It doesnt give me a 404 file not found, instead it loads the content of index.hml

How can I make it report an error 404 instead?

(Using vite 5.1.4)